# How to keep 1000 dynamic fragments inside viewpager android?

Tags: java, android

I need to show one thousands question with 4 options to fill using one activity. I got an idea to use viewpager, but cant able to show 1000 fragment.

Comment: @raghuM.tech Why to use fragments? You can do with single XML.

Comment: Can't able to show means ? Pls. share your code or logcat if there any errors or exception there.

Comment: So,you dont need 1000 fragments,you can use view pager and take your questions from a arraylist and displayed one by one using one fragment.

Comment: @VirRajpurohit Your way is 101% correct.

Answer (score 0):

It **is** possible to use `ViewPager` with 1000 fragments. Just make sure that your adapter extends [`FragmentStatePagerAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter).

From the documentation:

> This version of the pager is more useful when there are a large number
>   of pages, working more like a list view. When pages are not visible to
>   the user, their entire fragment may be destroyed, only keeping the
>   saved state of that fragment. This allows the pager to hold on to much
>   less memory associated with each visited page as compared to
>   FragmentPagerAdapter at the cost of potentially more overhead when
>   switching between pages.